# Impossible to create a field in domain class with ArrayList type in Grails

Tags: grails, collections

I need to create a domain class and I want to do a field there with `ArrayList<String>` type. But when I open a db-table, I can't find new field with `ArrayList<String>` type. It's impossible to create. But I can add to db-table a new field with `String`-type instead of `ArrayList<String>`. Where is cause? And which type of collection can I use instead of `ArrayList<String>` to I can successfully use it in domain class?

Comment: What db are you using that you think there is going to be a column type of ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are using a nosql database, you will simply create another table. In my example below, you would end up with two tables in the database... test and test_a. If you **are** using a nosql DB then you would get one document with an embedded list.

```
class Test {
    List<String> a

    static hasMany = [
        a: String
    ]
}
```